# How to update aspnet_compiler to 4.6.1?

Tags: .net, windows, aspnet-compiler

I have upgraded MVC project to 4.6.1 and since we're using a build server for CI, I installed .Net 4.6.1 developers kit on it too, alas the version of aspnet_compiler.exe stayed the same (unlike other computers where the same kit was installed).
Is there any way I can successfully update aspnet_compiler on Windows Server 2012 R2 to 4.6.1 withuot bypassing Windows security and copying it directly to C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ ?

EDIT:
I assumed ownership of all files and circumvented established security policies, then copies over my entire v4.0.30319 folder. That seemed to solve the problem, but today it's like that never happened. It's showing 4.0.30319 as aspnet_compiler.exe version.

EDIT2:
The problem went away when I upgraded all libraries in my project, including upgrade to MVC5. aspnet_compiler is still the wrong version, but now it has no problems building my views.

Answer (score -1):

aspnet_compiler.exe is part of .net framework. You can install [.net framework 4.6.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49982) on your machine to get the latest aspnet_compiler.exe.

Comment: .Net framework is part of win2012 system, it is not recommended to override it. If you want to update the version, why don't you install the new framework?

Comment: That's the first thing I did. That's why I'm asking the question. Because after I installed the new framework aspnet_compiler stayed the old version.

Comment: Seems there is some misunderstanding of .net 4.6.1 developer kit. What is it? Where did you download it?

Comment: Pardon, it's "Developer kit". (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978) 
It's .Net framework + updates for Visual studio and the like.

Comment: I see. I thought you meant framework SDK. Anyway, there is no diff between these two version of aspnet_compiler. You can still use the old one against your new project.

Comment: @mattfei I'm getting an error on a machine with the old version, but not on a machine with the new version, and I'd like to update just to eliminate the version as the source of the problem (and to keep environments in sync). Both machines have .NET 4.6.1 installed. Why would this not update? Infuriating!

Comment: @mattfei ASPCOMPILE is unable to load a class we named MvcApplication in the Global.asax.cs

Comment: @brianary since .net 4.5 is part of win2012, the .net 4.6.1 installer only updates the core .net dlls, e.g. clr.dll mscorlid, system.web.dll etc.. aspnet_compiler is not part of it. But if the old aspnet_compiler causes problem, it definitely should be fixed. I tried this on a mvc app, and didn't see the error you mentioned. Are you able to reproduce the issue with any mvc app or just your app?

Comment: @mattfei So far, just our app. Trying to narrow the differences between the environment with the error and the one without. This is the only obvious diff so far. Thanks for the info on server version, though! Safe to just copy aspnet_compiler.exe?